# Count the number of occurrences for each month

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe and wish to count and display occurrences of events per month as following. How do I do it?

I have a Pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
Name    Month

Jack    February
Jill    December
Bill    September
Jack    June
Jill    August
Bill    July
.
.
.
```

I wish to have a count of names born in each month and then display as follows:

```
Name    January   February   March  ...  December

Jack      0          6        10    ...     3
Jill      2          8         4    ...     2
Bill      4          5         9    ...     0
.
.
.
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Read the help pages for [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

Comment: Question #9 on the dup target should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Available data

```
   Name      Month
0  Jack   February
1  Jill   December
2  Bill  September
3  Jack       June
4  Jill     August
5  Bill       July
6  Mark       July
7  Mark       July
```

---

using `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')['Month']).reset_index().groupby('Name').sum()
```

**Output**

```
      August  December  February  July  June  September
Name                                                   
Bill       0         0         0     1     0          1
Jack       0         0         1     0     1          0
Jill       1         1         0     0     0          0
Mark       0         0         0     2     0          0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Both of the above approaches help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) here:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
          'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.Month).reindex(months, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

[out]

```
Month  January  February  March  April  May  June  July  August  September  \
Name                                                                         
Bill         0         0      0      0    0     0     1       0          1   
Jack         0         1      0      0    0     1     0       0          0   
Jill         0         0      0      0    0     0     0       1          0   

Month  October  November  December  
Name                                
Bill         0         0         0  
Jack         0         0         0  
Jill         0         0         1
```